# Disable warnings on a certain set of files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, suppress-warnings

Is there any way to disable a warning for a certain set of files in C# projects, without wrapping those files with `#pragma warning disable/restore` ?

I know I can disable specific warnings project-wide from the project settings, or with a `<NoWarn.. />` entry in the `.csproj` file, but that would be too coarse-grained.  I have some generated files that I'd rather not write docs for.

Edit: 
The compiler warning in question is [CS1591](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk18c1w9.aspx), or the famous "*Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'Type_or_Member'*" warning.

Using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Comment: Are these compiler warnings?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @MikeCheel - yes, see revised question.

Comment: @MarcelLamothe - VS 2013 community.

Comment: I have a feeling you might need to use a third party tool like ghost doc to do this. I am not sure if it is possible but Ghost Doc allows you to apply rules to namespaces and fields and such but I have never actually tried to do what you are asking. If these files are part of a specific namespace you can probably create an exception in ghost doc.

Comment: "I have some generated files that I'd rather not write docs for" => generated by what?  Anything you have control of?